# ng-model убирает отображение стандартного value из input'a, помогите поправить

Tags: html, angularjs

```
<input type="number" name="width" step="10" value="4000" ng-model="widthM">
```

ng-model убирает отображение стандартного value из input'a,
помогите поправить

Comment: Судя по всему, Вам надо заменить `value="4000"` на `ng-init="widthM=4000"`

Comment: @Yaant Все работает, спасибо

Comment: @Yaant возник такой же вопрос для radio и chekbox кнопок
`<label class="radio-inline"> <input type="radio" name="type"  ng-init="sum=false" ng-model="sum">`
!!!!!!!!!!
`<label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" name="type2"  value="{{calc.products.gate}}" ng-model="gateM" ng-true-value="{{calc.products.gate}}" ng-false-value="0"> Калитка</label>`